# Reader Mode for WebView in Flutter

Tags: flutter, webview, android-webview, flutter-web

I am developing an app with Flutter and I have to show webpages. I tried that using WebView and everything is ok.

However, there is an option in Swift with the SFSafariViewController which is called "entersReaderIfAvailable", if you set it to true and the webpage you are trying to show accepts the reader mode, then it opens in "Reader Mode"

If you don't know what is Reader Mode, you can check it here: https://www.nytimes.com/2018/07/03/technology/personaltech/safari-reader-mode.html

I know that Chrome supports the reader mode also.

But I have no idea if it is possible to do in Flutter.

Thanks in advance.

JRRM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly but there is no support for **"Reader Mode"** in Flutter WebView

As far as I know it's not even supported for Android WebView